# Having trouble with isUpper function in use

Tags: haskell

Is it OK to write the `otherwise` part this way? The function should lower the uppercase letters and put the space in front. It keeps giving an error.

```
functionl s
    | s==[]      = error "empty"
    | otherwise  = [ if isUpper c then (" " ++ toLower c) else c | c <-read s::[Char] ]
```

Comment: You are confusing characters and strings.  You can't concatenate (`++`) characters, only strings.  To convert a character `c` into a string use  `[c]`.  You also probably want to `concat` the list you are constructing.

Comment: Note that `read s :: [Char]` is the same as `s`.

Comment: @dfeuer No it isn't, e.g. `(read "\"hi\"" :: [Char]) == "hi"`, but you probably want to use `s` anyway.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, yes, you're right, of course. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Note that the return type of `(" "++ toLower c)` is a String (`[Char]`) if it was done properly - but it isn't. I'll show you below. 
But before that, note that in this specific list comprehension, you have `else c` which is a single `Char`.

Your return types must match.

This might be a suitable replacement: `concat [ if (isUpper c) then (" "++[c]) else [c] | c <-s ]`

Answer (score 4):

Your list comprehension is almost right as @Arnon has shown, but you could definitely implement this function more easily using recursion:

```
-- A descriptive name and a type signature help
-- tell other programmers what this function does
camelCaseToWords :: String -> String
camelCaseToWords [] = []
camelCaseToWords (c:cs)
    | isUpper c = ' ' : toLower c : camelCaseToWords cs
    | otherwise = c : camelCaseToWords cs
```

Now, this pattern can be abstracted to use a `fold`, which is Haskell's equivalent of a basic for-loop:

```
camelCaseToWords cs = foldr replacer [] cs
    where
        replacer c xs
            | isUpper c = ' ' : toLower c : xs
            | otherwise = c : xs
```

Here each step of the iteration is performed by `replacer`, which takes the current character `c`, an accumulated value `xs` and returns a new value to be used in the next iteration.  The fold is seeded with an initial value of `[]`, and then performed over the entire string.